# Does WordPress send data about your blog back to Automattic or somewhere else?

Tags: plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does WordPress send data about your blog to WordPress.org or Automattic?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64050/does-wordpress-send-data-about-your-blog-to-wordpress-org-or-automattic)

I've recently heard someone say that WordPress sends data about your blog to home (where ever that is). Is that true? and if so what is sent away or where in the code can I see what's exchanged?

Comment: please explain more, or give sources of where that said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true to a degree. They probably do this for a few reasons but most likely to help monitor bugs and things like that in regards to future improvements and updates. Nothing malicious to worry about! They need to keep track of versioning especially so that you can be notified of updates to WordPress itself as well as themes and plugins.

Your WordPress installation syncs up every 12 hours. A few things they keep track of: wordpress version, php version, locale, whether multisite is enabled, etc.

You can get a much better understanding of what they are tracking if you check out `includes/update.php` in your WordPress installation as everything is outlined in that file.