# Filter any HTTP request URI?

Tags: filters, urls, security, updates, http-api

I want to filter any HTTP request URI done through the HTTP API.

Use cases:

1. The WordPress update check goes to http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.6/, but https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.6/ works too, and I want to use this always.
2. The new WordPress file is taken from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.4.2.zip, but https://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.4.2.zip works too.
3. Sometimes I want to debug requests and redirect those temporary to a custom domain on my local server.
4. Some plugins make requests to other servers, and I want to replace these requests when the external server goes down.

The update requests are the most important ones for now, because there is still the unfixed [bug 16778](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16778) ([more information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64053/73)), and HTTPS requests lower the risk of a Man-in-the-middle attack.

I have [searched](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=008094839757605916882:f6pwe-gmjka&ie=UTF-8&q=filter%20request%20url%20wordpress) [thoroughly](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=filter%20http%20request%20uri), I have studied the core code … but ended up like Nacin two years ago:

> I thought for sure you could filter the URL of an HTTP request, but now I can't find one.

What did I miss? Did I? :)

Comment: Linking [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82676/385) here for anybody who searches for cURL debugging in WP.

Comment: There's now [a Trac ticket to add a filter for the request URL](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39400).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Less than an answer, but just a list of things straight from my experience with it - maybe you've overlooked something.

## Debugging the request & its results

Without diggin' too deep into the update process, but the WP HTTP API uses the `WP_HTTP` class. It also offers a nice thing: A debug hook.

```
do_action( 'http_api_debug', $response, 'response', $class, $args, $url );
```

Where `$response` can also be a `WP_Error` object that maybe tells you more.

Note: From a brief test, this filter seems to only (for some reason) work if you place it as *close* to where you're actually doing the request. So maybe you need to call it from within a callback on one of the below filters.

### `WP_HTTP` Class arguments

The Classes arguments itself are filterable, but afaik some get reset by the methods internals back to what WP assumes that is needed.

```
apply_filters( 'http_request_args', $r, $url );
```

One of the arguments is `ssl_verify`, which is true by default (but for me causes massive problems when updating from - for example - GitHub). *Edit:* After debugging a test request, I found another argument that is set to verify if SSL is set to `true`. It's called `sslverify` (without separating underscore). No idea where this came into the game, if it is actually in use or abandoned and if you have a chance to influence its value. I found it using the `'http_api_debug'` filter.

### Completely custom

You can also "simply" override the whole internals and go with a custom setup. There's a filter for that.

```
apply_filters( 'pre_http_request', false, $r, $url );
```

The first arg needs to be set to true. Than you can interact with the arguments inside `$r` and the result from `parse_url( $url );`.

### Proxy

Another thing that might work could be running everything through a custom Proxy. This needs some settings in your `wp-config.php`. I've never tried this before, but I ran through the constants a while back and summed up some examples that *should* work and included some comments in case I need it one day. You have to define `WP_PROXY_HOST` and `WP_PROXY_PORT` as a min. setting. Else nothing will work and it will simply bypass your proxy.

```
# HTTP Proxies
# Used for e.g. in Intranets
# Fixes Feeds as well
# Defines the proxy adresse.
define( 'WP_PROXY_HOST',          '127.0.84.1' );
# Defines the proxy port.
define( 'WP_PROXY_PORT',          '8080' );
# Defines the proxy username.
define( 'WP_PROXY_USERNAME',      'my_user_name' );
# Defines the proxy password.
define( 'WP_PROXY_PASSWORD',      'my_password' );
# Allows you to define some adresses which
# shouldn't be passed through a proxy.
define( 'WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS',  'localhost, www.example.com' );
```

#### EDIT

The `WP_HTTP` Class normally acts as *base* class (will be extended for different scenarios). The extending `WP_HTTP_*` classes are `Fsockopen`, `Streams`, `Curl`, `Proxy`, `Cookie`, `Encoding`. If you hook a callback to the `'http_api_debug'`-action, then the third argument will tell you which class was used for your request.

Inside the `WP_HTTP_curl` Class, you'll find the `request()` method. This method offers two filters to intercept the SSL behavior: One for local requests `'https_local_ssl_verify'` and one for remote requests `'https_ssl_verify'`. WP will likely define `local` as `localhost` and what you get in return from `get_option( 'siteurl' );`.

So what I'd do is to try the following right before you do that request (or from a callback that's hooked to the closest request:

```
add_filter( 'https_ssl_verify', '__return_true' );

# Local requests should be checked with something like
# 'localhost' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or similar
# add_filter( 'https_local_ssl_verify', '__return_true' );
```

Sidenote: In most cases `WP_HTTP_curl` will be used to handle Proxies.

Comment: Ah, I think you’ve answered my question indirectly: I can hook into `pre_http_request`, cancel the request and resend it with the correct URL. Will try that tonight.

Answer (score 9):

Based on @kaiser’s useful answer I have written some code that seems to work well. That is the reason why I marked it as The Answer.

Let me explain my solution …

### The logic

When a request it sent through the API is runs through `WP_Http::request()`. That’s the method with …

> @todo Refactor this code.

… in its header. I couldn’t agree more.

Now, there are some filters. I decided to misuse `pre_http_request` for my needs:

```
add_filter( 'pre_http_request', 't5_update_wp_per_https', 10, 3 );
```

We get three arguments here: `false, $r, $url`.

- `false` is the expected return value for `apply_filters()`. If we send anything else back,
  WordPress stops immediately, and the original request will not be sent.
- `$r` is an array of arguments for that request. We have to change these too in a minute.
- `$url` is – surprise! – the URL.

So in our callback `t5_update_wp_per_https()` we look at the URL, and if it is an URL we want to filter, we say **NO** to WordPress by *not* saying “no” (`false`).

[image]

Side note: It follows you can prevent all HTTP requests with:
`add_filter( 'pre_http_request', '__return_true' );`

We fire our own request instead with a better URL and slightly adjusted arguments
(`$r`, renamed to `$args` for readability).

### The code

Please read the inline comments, they are important.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Update WP per HTTPS
 * Description: Forces update checks and downloads for WP to use HTTPS.
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72529/filter-any-http-request-uri
 * Version:     2012.11.14
 * Author:      Fuxia Scholz
 * Author URI:  https://fuxia.me
 * Licence:     MIT
 * License URI: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

add_filter( 'pre_http_request', 't5_update_wp_per_https', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Force HTTPS requests for update checks and new WP version downloads.
 *
 * @wp-hook pre_http_request
 * @param   bool   $false
 * @param   array  $args
 * @param   string $url
 * @return  FALSE|array|object FALSE if everything is okay, an array of request
 *                            results or an WP_Error instance.
 */
function t5_update_wp_per_https( $false, $args, $url )
{
    // Split the URL into useful parts.
    $url_data = parse_url( $url );

    // It is already HTTPS.
    if ( 'https' === strtolower( $url_data['scheme'] ) )
        return FALSE;

    // Not our host.
    if ( FALSE === stripos( $url_data['host'], 'wordpress.org' ) )
        return FALSE;

    // Make that an HTTPS request.
    $new_url = substr_replace( $url, 'https', 0, 4 );

    // WP_Http cannot verify the wordpress.org certificate.
    $args['sslverify'] = FALSE;

    // It is slow. We wait at least 30 seconds.
    30 > $args['timeout'] and $args['timeout'] = 30;

    // Get an instance of WP_Http.
    $http    = _wp_http_get_object();

    // Get the result.
    $result = $http->request( $new_url, $args );

    /* prepend this line with a '#' to debug like a boss.
    print '<pre>'
    . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $result, TRUE ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE )
    . '</pre>';
    die();
    /**/

    return $result;
}
```

### The tests

Without that plugin WordPress used:

- `http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.6/` for update checks, and
- `http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.4.2.zip` to download the new files.

I tested it with two local installations, a single site and a multi-site setup on Win 7.
To force an update I set `$wp_version` in `wp-includes/version.php` to `1` and the version of
TwentyEleven to `1.3`.

To watch the network traffic I used [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/): It is free, it runs on Windows and Linux, and it offers some impressive filter tools.

Watching HTTPS is a little bit difficult: You see just encrypted data … that’s the idea after all.
To see if my plugin did what it should do I watched the unencrypted traffic first and noted the IP address used to connect to wordpress.org. That was `72.233.56.138`, sometimes `72.233.56.139`.
Not surprising, there is a load balancer and probably many other tools, so we cannot rely on **one** IP address.

Then I typed `ip.addr == 72.233.56.138` into the filter mask, activated the plugin, went to `wp-admin/update-core.php` and watched for the traffic in Wireshark. Green lines are requests in plain text – exactly what we don’t want. The red and black lines are a sign of success.

[image: Wireshark]

The update check went fine: It found the “newer” versions. The actual updates for the theme and the core went fine too. Exactly what I needed.

And still … that could be easier if there were a simple filter for the URL.

Comment: +1 for `/* /**/`, just because it's genius. And (if I could) another +1 for Charles Bronson. And then there should be another +1 for the detailed explanation, comments & screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

```
    add_filter('http_request_args', 'http_request_args_custom', 10,2);
    function http_request_args_custom($request,$url){
            if (strpos($url, 'wordpress.org') !== false){
                    global $replaced_url;
                    $replaced_url = 'http://wordpress.local';
            }
            return $request;
    }

    add_action('http_api_curl', 'http_api_curl_custom');
    function http_api_curl_custom(&$handle){
            global $replaced_url;
            if (!is_null($replaced_url))
                    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $replaced_url);
    }

    $http = new WP_Http();
    $response = $http->request('http://wordpress.org', array());

    var_dump($response);
```

Comment: It should be mentioned, that in this code example, in function http_api_curl_custom, global variable $replaced_url should be set to NULL after it was used. Otherwise, after first occurence of "wordpress.org" in the url, all other urls would be replaced.