# Import External XML

Tags: custom-post-types, database, xml

I don't know where to start with this one.

I would like to create custom post type which will list properties on clients website. I would like those properties being feed from another website/software. So other website/software will be sending XML file to my Wordpress site and I would like to receive that file and convert it to my custom posts.

Could anyone help me to get my head around this task, i.e. where to start? 
Do I need to create custom table in my database? 
How do I capture that XML file?
Any info would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Fetching the data

To fetch your posts, you'd utilize the [`HTTP_API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API), [`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) or [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/wiki/plugins/start). This completely depends on how and from where you're going to get the XML.

Here's one answer about the HTTP API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73659/385) and [another one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72540/385).

## Storing & maintaining the data

The main *problem* will be that you need a storage location. Therefore you'd go and set up a Custom Post Type and maybe some Custom Taxonomies as well. Just make sure that [they're properly registered to each other](http://wpkrauts.com/2013/registering-custom-taxonomies-for-custom-post-types-the-right-way/). The tough part will be inserting, updating and deleting the post data, meta data, authors and taxonomies terms.

## Retrieving the data on interval

Normally you'd [utilize the Transient API and/or the Schedule/Cron API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73659/385).

Answer (score 0):

I made such a script for our own company.

**My case:**

I needed a script that imported a list of XML files and made a post for every row in the file.

**What I did:**

- I made a CPT in wich I stored feed information
- In a script I created a XML import wich makes a post for every row
- The script was put in a cronjob that runs once a day to refresh the data

**My code:**

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/NAhspY20 (will expire in 30 days)

It wont be entirely what you are searching for, but I hope it will give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Can you post your code in your answer? Answers last a lot longer than pastebins 30 days. You may also want to try a more persistent service, I use gist.github.com but you might now others

Comment: Sadly this answer has a dead link. Do you still have code to add to here or shall we delete the answer?