# Formatting error while publishing theblog from Microsoft Word

Tags: posts, microsoft, windows-live-writer

I am trying to publish a blog post into wordpress based website from Microsoft Word. Here is the sample text that I added in Microsoft which I published as well.

> " Temporary Blog Post
>
> I am adding a temporary blog post here Let’s see how it goes
>
> Thanks"

However, when I published the post, this is how it looked

> /pI am adding a temporary blog post here
>
> /ppLet’s see how it goes
>
> /ppThanks

Any idea the reason behind the formatting error. I thought, when you publish from Microsofot word or Microsoft Live Writer, I was thinking, when published it looks the same as in the Microsoft Word.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Without seeing what data Word is sending to WordPress the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: How do I post the data that the word is sending ? Is there a possibility to check what Microsoft Word is sending ?

Comment: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) should do it. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72632/73) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

When pasting text from Microsoft Word, make sure you use the "Paste from Word" feature in the WYSIWYG editor. This can be done by clicking on the far right icon that looks like rainbow squares called "Show/Hide Kitchen Sink" ([image: Show/Hide Kitchen Sink]).

This will reveal a second row of icons, one with a "W" for Word ([image]). This helps strip a lot of the crap Word.

Also, if you don't need link/bold/bullet/etc formatting, you can use CMD + SHIFT + V (CTRL + SHIFT + V on Windows) to paste without formatting.